# Writing a local planner package

Tags: ros, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi people,

I am a newbie using ros for my school project, I have basic programming background (C language ). For my project, I am trying to simulate the collision avoidance behaviour of a robot.

So far I think the local planning package available on ros might not be able to exhibit the behaviour that my project required. This means that I will probably have to write a local planning package myself.

What I would like to know is what are the relevant knowledge of programming or computing require for me to be able to make changes to the local planner package, or even write out one myself?

Do I need to learn stuff like software development or computer network? Is C++ knowledge sufficient for writing my own package?

Any feedback will be appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47626/writing-a-local-planner-package/) by [Rookiebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/3536/rookiebot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[base_local_planner](http://ros.org/wiki/base_local_planner) and [dwa_local_planner](http://ros.org/wiki/dwa_local_planner) do collision avoidance based on a costmap that is normally built from lasers.

To understand the code, I would say a solid knowledge of C++ is definitely helpful. The same holds for creating your own packages. Have a look at the [ROS tutorials](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-11-07**:
So do you mean that we can edit dwa_local_planner just based on C++ knowledge?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-11-08**:
Sure, why not? It's open source. But, don't try to edit the /opt/ros tree, check out a source overlay and build that: http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays

**Comment by [Rookiebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/3536/rookiebot/) on 2012-11-14**:
Hi ppl,thanks for all the inputs. I have a clearer idea now.

**Comment by [RS](https://answers.ros.org/users/22821/rs/) on 2015-07-20**:
Hi Rookiebot! Did you edit parts of the local planner package? what is the best way to understand it?